# Index a torch tensor with an array

Tags: python, indexing, pytorch, tensor, torch

I have the following torch tensor:

```
tensor([[-0.2,  0.3],
    [-0.5,  0.1],
    [-0.4,  0.2]])
```

and the following numpy array: (I can convert it to something else if necessary)

```
[1 0 1]
```

I want to get the following tensor:

```
tensor([0.3, -0.5, 0.2])
```

i.e. I want the numpy array to index each sub-element of my tensor. Preferably without using a loop.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may want to use [`torch.gather`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.gather) - "Gathers values along an axis specified by dim."

```py
t = torch.tensor([[-0.2,  0.3],
    [-0.5,  0.1],
    [-0.4,  0.2]])
idxs = np.array([1,0,1])

idxs = torch.from_numpy(idxs).long().unsqueeze(1)  
# or   torch.from_numpy(idxs).long().view(-1,1)
```

```py
t.gather(1, idxs)
tensor([[ 0.3000],
        [-0.5000],
        [ 0.2000]])
```

Here, your index is numpy array so you have to convert it to LongTensor.

Comment: I chose this answer since it is faster when the tensor is big

Answer (score 3):

Just simply, use a range(len(index)) for the first dimension.

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor([[-0.2,  0.3],
    [-0.5,  0.1],
    [-0.4,  0.2]])

c = [1, 0, 1]


b = a[range(3),c]

print(b)
```